# In Windows, the MacBook Pro fails to get IPv6 settings via DHCPv6

Tags: network, bootcamp, windows

I have Windows 10 installed on my MacBook Pro (the latest 15" version with discrete GPU). I also have IPv6 connectivity on my home WiFi network, which is managed by a DHCPv6 server.

In OS X, setting IPv6 to `Automatic` causes it to pull the correct address and DNS settings from the DHCPv6 server. In Windows, on the same machine, it does not.

The thing is, it *did* work once, *before* I installed Boot Camp drivers on the Windows side. Yesterday the "upgrade" process to the new "Windows 10 1511" release looked as if it basically reinstalled Windows, and afterwards my DHCPv6 issue was temporarily fixed. That is, until I also ran the Boot Camp update, then things stopped working again.

I tried uninstalling the Broadcom wireless driver package via Control Panel, but rather than going back to whatever it was using by default, Windows just fails to find a driver for it completely.

Can anyone tell me: right after a fresh Windows install and **before** you install the Boot Camp software, what driver does Windows use for the wireless card in the latest 15" MBP?

Comment: +1 for the clear request for more data - hopefully someone sees this before they start their next boot camp install. If you decide to wipe your boot camp and start over - have a look at [WinClone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) - the support team at Two Canoes might be a great resource as would superuser.com to ask how to troubleshoot DHCP over IPv6 under windows.